# Segmentation fault looking for longest strings in a vector

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, vector, function-definition

Given an array of strings, return another array containing all of its longest strings. The solution I developed is available below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<string> solution(vector<string> ia) {
  int maxi = -1;
  int size = ia.size();
  vector<string> iasol;

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    int m = ia[i].length();
    cout << m << " " << maxi << endl;
  
    if (m > maxi)
      maxi = m;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    int m = ia[i].length();
  
    if (m == maxi) {
      iasol[i] = ia[i];
      cout << iasol[i];
    }
  }
  return iasol;
}

int main() {
    vector<string> inputArray = {"aba", "aa", "ad", "vcd", "aba"};
    solution(inputArray);
}
```

The program is expected to work as follows:

```
INPUT
inputArray ← ["aba", "aa", "ad", "vcd", "aba"]

OUTPUT
solution(inputArray) → ["aba", "vcd", "aba"]
```

The above solution gives the following error:

```
3 -1
2 3
2 3
3 3
3 3
Segmentation fault
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: How many strings are in your `iasol` vector?  (Zero.  There are none.)

Comment: In your 2nd loop, you're indexing into an empty vector.  You cannot do that to insert, you can only do that to access an _alrady-existing_ element.  Instead of `iasol[i]=ia[i];` do `iasol.push_back(ia[i]);`

Comment: Also, this is solvable in a single pass over the data.

Comment: Change your usage of `[]` to use `at()`.  Then you will not get a segmentation-fault, but you will get an `std::out_of_range` exception thrown, telling you what you are doing wrong.

Comment: [Here is an example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f1f2f77b31b10bf).  Just one usage of `at()` in the right place determined the issue.  Fixing the issue is given in the answer section(s).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Since I found the readability of the source code you developed low, I developed a new solution for this problem.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

/* Returns the size of the vector with the maximum length. */
size_t getMaximumSize(vector<string> input);

/* Returns a vector container based on the string length. */
vector<string> getElementBySize(vector<string> input, size_t size);

/* Prints the vector container. */
void print(vector<string> input);

int main()
{
    vector<string> input{"aba", "aa", "ad", "vcd", "aba"};
    print(getElementBySize(input, getMaximumSize(input)));
    return 0;
}

vector<string> getElementBySize(vector<string> input, size_t size)
{
    vector<string> result;
    
    for(int i = 0 ; i < input.size(); ++i)
        if(input[i].size() == size)
            result.push_back(input[i]);
            
    return result;
}

size_t getMaximumSize(vector<string> input)
{
    size_t maximumNumberOfCharacters = input[0].size();

    for(int i = 0 ; i < input.size() - 1 ; ++i)
        if(input[i].size() < input[i+1].size())
            maximumNumberOfCharacters = input[i+1].size();
    
    return maximumNumberOfCharacters;
}

void print(vector<string> input)
{
    for(string i : input)
        cout << i << ' ';
}
```

---

This program produces the following output:

```
aba vcd aba
```

Comment: The "answer" does not tell what was the OP did wrong and results in the segmentation fault.

Comment: An additional note. Don't suggest the usage of `using namespace std;`.  `getMaximumSize`, `print` and `getElementBySize` create a copy of the input vector, this is not a problem for smaller vector, but not a good approach.

Comment: I didn't want to specify additionally because it was said what the problem was; it needed to use the `push_back()` method to add elements to the vector container.

Comment: [See this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4581624c191f5bd0).  Uses more space, of course.

Comment: Sure, but an answer should stand for itself. Who guarantees that the other answer won't be deleted (or changed), or that other answers will be added with incorrect explanations.

Comment: The post owner will probably see how data is added to the container when he examines the `getElementBySize()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `iasol` is initially empty so indexing it with *any* value of `i` will be out of bounds. `std::vector` grows when you add elements to it. Instead of `iasol[i] = ia[i];` in your second loop, do `iasol.push_back(ia[i]);` to add it to the result. [live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CkxqIiVf4lFmjmLh)

I'd also recommend using ranged-for rather than index-based to make this clearer.

```
std::vector<std::string> solution(const std::vector<std::string>& input) {
  std::size_t max_size{};
  for (const auto& s : input) {
    auto sz = s.size();
    if (sz > max_size) {
      max_size = sz;
    }
  }
  
  std::vector<std::string> longest_strings;
  for (const auto& s : input) {
    if (s.size() == max_size) {
      longest_strings.push_back(s);
    }
  }
  return longest_strings;
}
```

[live link](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Lt8EmbQC7FaJiFJr)

Answer (score 0):

The vector declared like

```
vector<string> iasol;
```

has no elements. So this statement

```
iasol[i] = ia[i];
```

invokes undefined behavior.

What you  need is to apply two standard algorithms `std::max_element` and `std::copy_if`.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<std::string> solution( const std::vector<std::string> &v )
{
    auto it = std::max_element( std::begin( v ), std::end( v ),
        []( const auto &s1, const auto &s2 )
        {
            return s1.size() < s2.size();
        } );

    auto n = it->size();

    std::vector<std::string> result;

    std::copy_if( std::begin( v ), std::end( v ), std::back_inserter( result ),
        [&n]( const auto &s ) 
        { 
            return s.size() == n; 
        } );

    return result;
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> v = { "aba", "aa", "ad", "vcd", "aba" };

    auto result = solution( v );

    for (const auto &s : result)
    {
        std::cout << s << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
aba vcd aba
```